# Application Insights Python Flush() hangs inside docker container

Tags: python, azure, azure-application-insights

`tc.flush()` works fine in my python script. However, when I run it inside a Windows nano docker container, my python script hangs at `tc.flush()`. Commenting out `tc.flush()` results in the scripting running fine, but nothing is being sent/received by App Insights. I've tried the other suggestions as described at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Python/issues/16 but nothing seems to work.

I've created an issue for it at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Python/issues/67

Using applicationinsights==0.11.1

Comment: Your two links are same,please modify it and let us know what suggestions you tried.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the links.